# Escaping `%` symbol in query parameter in JAX-RS

Tags: java, escaping, jax-rs, resteasy, jersey-client

I try to send GET request with some URL string as a parameter using any of Jersey or Resteasy

```
Response response = new ResteasyClientBuilder()
        .build()
        .target(UriBuilder.fromPath("https://foo.bar"))
        .queryParam("url", "http://hostname.com/The%20URL%20with spaces.jpg")
        .request()
        .get();
```

Both implementations send
`https://foo.bar?url=http%3A%2F%2Fhostname.com%2FThe%20URL%20with%20spaces.jpg`

I assume that original space is escaped with `%20` and original `%20` is double-escaped in the query parameter.
But it isn't.
Original space and `%20` are mixed, and on the server side I get unescaped string with all `%20` converted to spaces and the string gets broken.

According to [source code of Resteasy](https://github.com/resteasy/Resteasy/blob/b8997dc239dffcf9a46ae6c0cd2d1fe628cf83e4/resteasy-jaxrs/src/main/java/org/jboss/resteasy/util/Encode.java#L205), it "Keeps encoded values "%..." and template parameters intact". But I haven't found any word in the JEE docs about this behavior.

Should I escape my string before adding it as a parameter?
What escaper should I use to be sure that it escapes all of `"%..." and template parameters`, and everithing it escapes in a parameter is successfully unescaped by server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution for standard JAX-RS `WebTarget` is to not apply parameters directly but apply them as template parameters.

```
Response response = new ResteasyClientBuilder()
        .build()
        .target(UriBuilder.fromPath("https://foo.bar"))
        .queryParam("url", "{urlTemplate}")
        .resolveTemplate("urlTemplate", "http://hostname.com/The%20URL%20with spaces.jpg")
        .request()
        .get();
```

First, we add some template `{urlTemplate}` as a parameter value, and then render this template with the real value.
`WebTarget` always assumes that the given parameter as a possible template, and doesn't escape some characters
But `.resolveTemplate()` guarantees escaping of all characters that should be escaped