# How can I encode invalid URI characters in a queryParam value of javax.ws.rs.client.WebTarget (JAX-RS)?

Tags: java

I have the following method that makes an API call to the outside world:

```
import javax.ws.rs.client.Client;
import javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder;
import javax.ws.rs.client.WebTarget;

public Optional<Product> getProductBySku(String user, String sku) {
    Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
    WebTarget webTarget = client.target("http://localhost:8080");
    return webTarget
        .path("product")
        .queryParam("sku", sku)
        .queryParam("user", user)
        .request()
        .header("X-Request-Id", Xmdc.get("requestId"))
        .get(Product.class));
}
```

Let's assume we have 2 SKUs: "XBox" and "AgeOfEmpires{2"
The problem is that for certain URI invalid characters in the SKU, like "{" -- which is probably bad naming for a SKU, but it happens -- the execution fails with the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Illegal character "&" at position 18 is not allowed as a part of a name in a path template "sku=AgeOfEmpires{2&user=test"
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyWebTarget.getUri(JerseyWebTarget.java:111)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyWebTarget.request(JerseyWebTarget.java:191)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyWebTarget.request(JerseyWebTarget.java:36)
```

Which I know it's an issue with using the "{" character in the URI.

I come from the JavaScript world, where I can use `encodeURIComponent(sku)` and will result in `"AgeOfEmpires%7B2"`, and that would be a valid URI. What would be the equivalent here for Java?

I was expecting that the functionality could be built in, since I saw there is a class `javax.ws.rs.client.WebTarget.getUriBuilder`. If it's not automatically taken care of, how can I combine the two classes to escape the invalid characters in the `queryParam`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Escaping \`%\` symbol in query parameter in JAX-RS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52121737/escaping-symbol-in-query-parameter-in-jax-rs)